# How to fix spanish quotation symbols?

Tags: babel, quoting, spanish

I am using the Babel package to write a document in spanish. Everything seems to work fine except for the quotation marks: " and " (actually they are the same symbol, but come in pairs). The problem I am experiencing is inconsistency, sometimes they work correctly some times I get strange symbols like ç.

Looking online I found one solution is to use the symbols: `` ''. I was wondering if there is a way to make the symbol " to work correctly, or maybe other consistent solution.

Answer (score 6):

Don't use `"` to write quotes, that it is the wrong input. `"` is in a number of languages (and also in spanish) an active character, a command, that is used as a shorthand for other commands. In spanish you can use e.g. `"<` to get a left quote. Personally I always use the package `csquotes` and `\enquote` to write quotes, as this adapt to other languages automatically:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\begin{document}

"<spanish quotes">

\enquote{algún texto con \enquote{una cita interior} como ejemplo}

\selectlanguage{english}
\enquote{some text with \enquote{an inner quote} as an example}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I'll look into that. However I was wondering if there is a way to obtain the symbols " ", were the opening and closing quotes are the same; the one you provided is a close approximation but the opening quote is different from the closing quote.

Comment: you can use `\textquotedbl` to get the straight quote symbol, you can also configure csquotes to use it. But `\textquotedbl` is not the correct typografical quote symbol, it should (outside code listings) only be used if you want to give your text a "typewriter" look and feel.